# To and From JSON for custom data types

Tags: json, haskell

I have the following classes:

```
type ID = UUID

data MySubClass1 = MySubClass1
    { sVar1 :: UTCTime
    , sVar2 :: UTCTime
    }

data MyMainClass = MyMainClass
    { var1 :: ID
    , var2 :: MySubClass1
    , var3 :: (Int, String)
    , var4 :: Maybe String
    }
```

And here's JSON itself:

```
{
  "var1" : ...,
  "var2_1": ...,
  "var2_2": ...,
  "var3_1": ...,
  "var3_2": ...,
  "var4": ...,

  "svar1": ...,
  "svar2": ...
}
```

And I need to create the instances of JSON for them:

```
--OK
instance FromJSON MySubClass1 where
  parseJSON (Object v) = 
    MySubClass1 <$> v .: "svar1" 
           <*> v .: "svar2" 

--OK
instance ToJSON MySubClass1 where
  toJSON (MySubClass1 sVar1 sVar2) =
    object ["svar1" .= sVar1
      , "svar2" .= sVar2
    ]
```

And here's I have a difficulty

```
instance FromJSON MyMainClass where
  parseJSON (Object v) = 
    MyMainClass <$> v .: "var1" 
           <*> (MySubClass1 v .: "var2_1" v .: "var2_2") -- error
           <*> (v .: "var3_1" v .: "var3_2") -- error
           <*> v .:? "var4" 

instance ToJSON MyMainClass where
  toJSON (MyMainClass var1 var2 var3 var4) =
    object ["var1" .= var1
      , "var2" .= ---???
      , -- what's next?
    ]
```

Most of the errors say that the types don't match.

Comment: You have errors because your code is pretty malformed.  For example on the line `<*> (v .: "var3_1" v .: "var3_2")`, you probably really want `<*> ((,) <$> v .: "var3_1" <*> v .: "var3_2")`, as this will actually construct a tuple out of those two values.  Having `v .: "var3_1" v .: "var3_2"` makes it look like to the compiler that you're trying `v .: ("var3_1" v) .: "var3_2"` since function application binds more tightly than all operators, and `"var3_1" v` doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @bheklilr, I've fixed FromJson, thank you. Could you help me fix ToJson?

Comment: You just have to keep doing what you're doing.  Just do `object ["var1" .= var1, "var2_1" .= sVar1 var2, "var2_2" .= sVar2 var2, "var3_1" .= fst var3, "var3_2" .= snd var3, ...]`.

Comment: I will suggest that you change up your JSON structure a bit though.  It'd be better of your `MySubClass1` was an entire sub-object in the JSON structure, so you could have `{"var1": "UUID", "var2": {"svar1": "12345", "svar2": "67890"}, ...}` and so on.